# Need to select all the input fileds and validate it one by one with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, validation

I have a Requirement to validate all the inputs that are in my form to be validated in the keyup function of each and every input.

My question is can I do it with out writing validation to each and every input filed. (using `each();` or some other method)...

Sorry for my silly question guys.

```
'        
        $(".required:input").each(function validate() {
            $(this).keyup(function(){

                var input=$(this).val();

            if (input == '') {

                $('.SpRequired').html("<img src='img/stop.png' style='width:25px;'>").show('slow');
                    return false;


            }
            else {

              $('.SpRequired').html("<img src='img/right.png' style='width:5px;'>").show('slow');
                return true;

            }


        });


    });'
```

this is what i Wrote correct me Please

Comment: Yes you can.  Show us what you've tried and explain what happened and how it didn't work.

Comment: http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: `$("input").keyup(function() {` ?

Comment: https://github.com/DiegoLopesLima/Validate seems to be a pretty fair plugin as alternative to the more common https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation (as mentioned by @RoryMcCrossan). Diego Lopes' Plugin is very well documented on his github page and even offers an onKeyup option parameter very useful for your case.

Comment: I need not to use 3rd party plugins I prefer to write my own validations (I know its dame silly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("input").keyup(function() {
   //whatever you want to validate
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MhQP3/2/)

Comment: I need not to use 3rd party plugins I prefer to write my own validations (I know its dame silly)

Comment: You don't need to use any 3rd party plugins. The only 3rd party plugin used in the code above is jQuery. Do you want to do it with pure JS?

Comment: @Binku saw the code in your question - works perfectly well for me, see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MhQP3/2/). But i would refactor `$(".required:input").each(function validate() { $(this).keyup(function(){` to `$(".required:input").keyup(function() { ... });`, as the way you do it, it is just not neccessary and kinda redundant.